# How to do this SQL request in laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel

How to do this request in laravel 4.2 :

```
    SELECT 
`p`.`id_pseudo`,
`nom`,
`prenom`,
`email`,
`code_court_etat`,
DATE_FORMAT(pv.date_visite, '%d/%m/%Y %h:%i') AS date_derniere_visite,
COUNT(pp.id_pseudo_produit) AS qte_produit
FROM
`pseudo` AS `p`
    LEFT JOIN
`pseudo_produit` AS `pp` ON `p`.`id_pseudo` = `pp`.`id_pseudo`
    LEFT JOIN
`pseudo_visite` AS `pv` ON `pv`.`id_pseudo` = `p`.`id_pseudo`
    AND `date_visite` = select max(date_visite) from pseudo_visite where id_pseudo = p.id_pseudo
GROUP BY `p`.`id_pseudo` , `nom` , `prenom` , `email` , `code_court_etat` , `date_derniere_visite`
ORDER BY `p`.`nom` ASC , `p`.`prenom` ASC
```

I tried :

```
$requete = DB::table('pseudo as p')
        ->leftjoin('pseudo_produit as pp', 'p.id_pseudo', '=', 'pp.id_pseudo')
        ->leftJoin('pseudo_visite as pv', function($join) 
                { 
                    $join->on('pv.id_pseudo', '=', 'p.id_pseudo')
                    ->where('date_visite', '=', DB::raw('select max(date_visite) from pseudo_visite where id_pseudo = p.id_pseudo'));

                })  
        ->select('p.id_pseudo', 'nom', 'prenom', 'email', 'code_court_etat', 
                DB::raw('date_format(pv.date_visite, "%d/%m/%Y %h:%i") as date_derniere_visite'),
                DB::raw('count(pp.id_pseudo_produit) as qte_produit'))
        ->orderby('p.nom','asc')->orderby('p.prenom', 'asc')
        ->groupBy('p.id_pseudo', 'nom', 'prenom', 'email', 'code_court_etat', 'date_derniere_visite');
```

without success. Because there is a not wanted quote in the subquery which appears.

Any help will be appreciated.

dominique

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the answer you're looking for, but you don't *have* to use the Query Builder just because it's Laravel. You can use raw queries in cases where the Query Builder is inefficient or otherwise ineffective.

Take a look at the [Database Documentation](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/database#running-queries). You already have the query, so you could just run it:

```
$results = DB::select('...');
```

Your `$results` will be an array of the rows returned.

Comment: yes you're right, but I have to add some "->Where" at this request. That's why I prefer Query Builder. It s easier to write....except when there is a subquery like this request. This query builder almost works, there is just a " around the subquery "select max....." , and of course it does not work because this ". Any other suggestion to build this query ?

Comment: I decided to make this request with a view. I spent too much time on this query builder.